# What is the meaning of idiom 'burning holes in eyes'?

Tags: idioms

> His shorts are burning holes in my eyes.

'Burn holes in pocket' refers to making money come out of pocket.So 'burn holes in eyes' may be making the eyeballs to pop out of eyes.Is not it?

Also aside, which is correct 'Good choice at/on carrier'?

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time.

Comment: I don't agree that 'burning holes in eyes' is an idiom in the first place, so it's entirely a matter of opinion what someone might intend it to mean in any given context.

Comment: "Don't stare so much, you might burn a hole in it!" is an expression since staring is considered impolite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have not provided enough of an extract for readers to understand the context of the phrase. However, such a phrase is usually used to indicate that something is a very bright colour or an extreme pattern that offends the eye. The phrase "burning eyes" refers to something as bright as the sun.

It is implying the shorts  are so ugly that the writer had to look away to protect their eyes.